# Unable to locate excess margin making my page more than 100% width

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a section on one of my pages that is increasing the width of the mobile viewprt more than 100% width. I am unable to locate it and am not sure why it is doing it. When the screen is in a mobile viewport, my green box takes up the full width of the screen, so that is where it can be seen.

Does anyone see why the extra margin is being applied?

[image]

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
.project_arrow_box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(69, 186, 149);
  border: 4px solid rgb(69, 186, 149);
  width: 33%;
  height: 800px;
  z-index: 99;
}
.project_arrow_box:after,
.project_arrow_box:before {
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.project_arrow_box:after {
  border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left-color: rgb(69, 186, 149);
  border-width: 40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
.project_arrow_box:before {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left-color: rgb(69, 186, 149);
  border-width: 26px;
  margin-top: -26px;
}
#project-content-wrap {
  margin: 30% 13%;
}
#project-box-title1 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #FFF;
}
#project-box-title2 {
  font-size: 10vmin;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#project-box-description {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #303030;
  margin-top: 50px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
/*----------------------------------------------PHONE MEDIA QUERY 640--------------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .project_arrow_box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
  }
  .project_arrow_box:after,
  .project_arrow_box:before {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  .project_arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-top-color: rgb(69, 186, 149);
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
  }
  .project_arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-top-color: rgb(69, 186, 149);
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-left: -36px;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  #project-content-wrap {
    margin: 10% 5%;
  }
  #project-box-title1 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  #project-box-description {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #303030;
    margin-top: 40px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="project_arrow_box">
  <div id="project-content-wrap">
    <div id="project-box-title1">KICK START YOUR</div>
    <div id="project-box-title2">PROJECT</div>
    <div id="project-box-description">We enjoy partnering with established brands from all over the globe. To begin the process please provide us with a high level overview and submit our form. We will review and respond promptly.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, exactly the width of my browser's window.

Comment: Please see updated question with image. This is how it appears on my phone and on a smaller viewport on my desktop.

Comment: that code snippet is not showing some code element you have on the screenshot like the menu...in order to see whats causing it i think we need to see the whole code

Comment: Actually your other page has more than one element causing trouble.

Comment: @rac Then what is? I don't see anything sticking out.

Comment: See my answer. All the input fields are sticking out. You have to inspect them and see for yourself. You're making a bit of a mess, mixing margins and paddings in pixels, with widths in %. You should set those elements to `border-box`, give them % margins/paddings, or rethink your whole approach and add margin/padding to parents, while letting the children take up 100% width.

Comment: @rac When I make them smaller, it still doesn't help. And I have them set for 87% of the width of the container. So I am not sure how they are too large.

Comment: Alright, I'm out of ideas. I saw your page, and made the changes I suggested you. After doing that, the page looks fine to me, it stops extending beyond the window. Sorry!

Comment: @rac it is like there is a shadow when you hover over the green section on the right margin that exceeds past the 100 viewport width.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't figure out where that shadow was coming from.

Answer (score 3):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.project_arrow_box` inside the 640px media query. It has a 4px border that's incompatible with having its width set to 100%. You're putting an extra 8px on top of the 100%.

When you use 100% as the width of an block-type element, it will take up 100% of the width of its parent. However, you're then assigning a border to it, which has to extend beyond the width of the parent.

After you set `border-sizing` to `border-box`, the browser will *‘paint’* the paddings, margins, and borders of that element as a subtraction of its width.

Expanding on my answer: your other page has a couple of extra problems, the core of which is this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
    .input-borderless
```

These inputs are all too large and extend past the body of the page.

Comment: You should probably elaborate on why this is necessary.